# Trigger to insert multiple record

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete, database-trigger

I'm trying to create a trigger to insert all the value that I delete from a table in a "Backup" table,
Ex:

```
Table 1: NomePilota, ModelloVettura, NomeScuderia

BackupTable1 (Table 2): NomePilota, ModelloVettura, NomeScuderia
```

What I want from the trigger to do: Insert into 'Table 2' deleted values from table 1.

I tried like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Backup ON dbo.Table1 AFTER (i can only use after) DELETE AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @Pilota VARCHAR(20) = (SELECT NomePilota FROM deleted)

  DECLARE @Vettura VARCHAR(50) = (SELECT ModelloVettura FROM deleted)

  DECLARE @Scuderia VARCHAR(20) = (SELECT NomeScuderia FROM deleted)

  INSERT INTO Table2 (NomePilota, ModelloVettura, NomeScuderia) VALUES (@Pilota, @Vettura, @Scuderia)
```

But it send a error:

> Cannot insert multiple records in @Pilota, @Vet, @Scud

How can I fix that? Does the deleted table already have a default ID column to use like in a for? Can I use something like vectors? (like `@Nome[] = SELECT * FROM Tabella`, `Insert into Tabella2 (Nome) VALUES @Nome`[@Numero (numero is like the record number of nome]).

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? You used two mysql-related tags, but also the sql-server tag. Also the DECLARE syntax you show seems to be Microsoft SQL Server syntax (MySQL doesn't use the `@` sigil before local variables in a trigger). So which is it?

Comment: As the error message clearly states, there are multiple rows returned from your select queries...

Comment: With the `@var` declarations, the `dbo.` quallifer and references to `deleted`, we can be pretty sure this is Transact-SQL (MIcrosoft SQL Server) and not MySQL

Comment: Check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) you need a good understanding of how SQL Server triggers work before embarking on this. As `Inserted` and `Deleted` can have multiple rows you have to handle this in your trigger. Ideally using proper set based logic, but otherwise row by row operations.

Answer (score 3):

Why not make life simple?

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (NomePilota, ModelloVettura, NomeScuderia) 
   SELECT NomePilota, ModelloVettura, NomeScuderia FROM deleted
```

The insert statment can work on the results of a select -- here we leverage this to simplify the task at hand.

Comment: This is a million times better than what the OP was trying to do. Why? Because this is set based and doesn't follow the anti-pattern posted by the OP where the code assumes there will only be a single row in deleted.

Comment: (I hope OP can figure out that this means the three DECLARE statements should be eliminated,)

Comment: i was doing with the DECLARE cause the software i'm using doesn't support the INSERT SELECT so i first needed to put the values in a variable and then inserting them, so counting this, how can i do that?

Comment: what software is that lorenzo?

Comment: it's Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17, the free, student version @Hogan

Comment: @LorenzoMontini I assure you that SSMS 2017 supports this type of insert statement. What made you decide that your version doesn't?

Comment: @LorenzoMontini -- that should support it just fine.

Comment: Because last time i tried ti use an Insert Select It doesn"t work and returned me an error